# Inline background image Retina detection

Tags: css

In my HTML I am seeking to do inline retina detection to display a background image in a div. At present, I just cannot get the Retina image to appear - Only the standard res one.

My code example is below. 
Any tips to steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="
background-image:url('assets/images/image.jpg');
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
background-image:url('assets/images/image@2x.jpg');
}
">
Hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this! According to the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax), media queries cannot exist in inline style attributes as they can only contain `property: value` declarations.

You should define your media queries in an external css file, or internally under `<style>` in the `<head>` section